# php information not passing through with sessions and pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So I've been looking at this page for hours and hours and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is here. I had this issues with all links previously, where I would lick a link to filter/sort database results, click a page link to go to the next page and it would display the second page without any filtered results. I resolved this for "Most Wins", "Best Save %" and "Best Goals Against" by the use of sessions, but for some reason it is still doing this when I try and filter results via my range sliders form. It works when I adjust the sliders, and submit, but if I click another page, once again, it show all results in the database. Can anyone see as to why it might be doing this? I've tried both post and get methods from the form but it didn't seem to work, but if anyone could provide some advice I would greatly appreciate it!!

Here is the code:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header-container">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.php"><img src="images/header_img.png" alt="Golaie Gear Online"/></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="listings.php?listing=default">Browse Goalies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gearlist.php">Browse Gear</a></li>
                    <li><a href="admin/login.php" style="color:#9a9a9a;">Admin</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form method="get" action="<?php echo "generalsearch.php?q=$searchvalue"; ?>" class="search-field">
                        <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                        <button type="submit" title="Search" id="submit"><img src="images/header_srch.png" alt="search"/></button>
                </form>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>


    </header>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<style type="text/css">

#win-range, #gaa-range, #sv-range{
    width: 160px;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;     
}
#win-range a, #gaa-range a, #sv-range a{
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){

    $("#win-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 1000,
    values: [1, 1000],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        // in order to pass the user selected values to your app, we will use jQuery to prepopulate certain hidden form elements, then grab those values from the $_POST
        $("#minwins").val(ui.values[0]);
        $("#maxwins").val(ui.values[1]);
        $("#winamount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
    }
});
$("#winamount").val($("#win-range").slider("values", 0) + " - " + $("#win-range").slider("values", 1));

    });
$(function(){

    $("#gaa-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    values: [0, 10],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        // in order to pass the user selected values to your app, we will use jQuery to prepopulate certain hidden form elements, then grab those values from the $_POST
        $("#mingaa").val(ui.values[0]);
        $("#maxgaa").val(ui.values[1]);
        $("#gaaamount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
    }
});
$("#gaaamount").val($("#gaa-range").slider("values", 0) + " - " + $("#gaa-range").slider("values", 1));

    });
$(function(){

    $("#sv-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 750,
    max: 1000,
    values: [750, 1000],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        // in order to pass the user selected values to your app, we will use jQuery to prepopulate certain hidden form elements, then grab those values from the $_POST
        $("#minsv").val(ui.values[0]);
        $("#maxsv").val(ui.values[1]);
        $("#svamount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
    }
});
$("#svamount").val($("#sv-range").slider("values", 0) + " - " + $("#sv-range").slider("values", 1));

    });
</script>

<?php 
include("includes/header.php");
include("includes/mysqli_connect.php");

$sortDesc = $_REQUEST['sortstats'];
$sortAsc = $_REQUEST['sortstatslow'];
$minwins = $_GET['minwins'];
$maxwins = $_GET['maxwins'];
$mingaa = $_GET['mingaa'];
$maxgaa = $_GET['maxgaa'];
$minsv = $_GET['minsv'];
$maxsv = $_GET['maxsv'];
// FILTERING YOUR DB
$sortstats = $_GET['sortstats'];
$sortstatslow = $_GET['sortstatslow'];
$getminwins = $_REQUEST['getminwins'];
$getmaxwins = $_REQUEST['getmaxwins'];
$getmingaa = $_REQUEST['getmingaa'];
$getmaxgaa = $_REQUEST['getmaxgaa'];
$getminsv = $_REQUEST['getminsv'];
$getmaxsv = $_REQUEST['getmaxsv'];
// paging
        $getcount = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Player");
        $postnum = mysqli_result($getcount,0);// this needs a fix for MySQLi upgrade; see custom function below
        $limit = 6; //how many blog posts per page you will see.
        if($postnum > $limit){
        $tagend = round($postnum % $limit,0);
        $splits = round(($postnum - $tagend)/$limit,0);

        if($tagend == 0){
        $num_pages = $splits;
        }else{
        $num_pages = $splits + 1;
        }

        if(isset($_GET['pg'])){
        $pg = $_GET['pg'];
        }else{
        $pg = 1;
        }
        $startpos = ($pg*$limit)-$limit;
        $limstring = "LIMIT $startpos,$limit";
        }else{
        $limstring = "LIMIT 0,$limit";
        }

        // MySQLi upgrade: we need this for mysql_result() equivalent
        function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
            $res->data_seek($row); 
            $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
            return $datarow[$field]; 
        }


?>
<div class="listingcontainer">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <h3>Sort By:</h3>
        <a href="listings.php?sortstats=Wins">Most Wins</a>
        <a href="listings.php?sortstatslow=GAA">Best Goals Against</a>
        <a href="listings.php?sortstats=SavePerc">Best Save %</a>
        <hr/>
        <h3>Custom Filter</h3>
        <br/>
        <div class="custom-filter">
            <form name="filters" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get" id="filters">
                <label for="winamount">Win Range:</label>
                <input type="text" id="winamount" />
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <input type="hidden" id="minwins" name="minwins" value="0" />
                <input type="hidden" id="maxwins" name="maxwins" value="1000" />
               <div id="win-range"></div>
               <br/>
               <label for="gaaamount">GAA:</label>
                <input type="text" id="gaaamount" /><br />
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <input type="hidden" id="mingaa" name="mingaa" value="0" />
                <input type="hidden" id="maxgaa" name="maxgaa" value="10" />
               <div id="gaa-range"></div>
                <br/>
               <label for="svamount">SV %:</label>
                <input type="text" id="svamount" /><br />
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <input type="hidden" id="minsv" name="minsv" value="750" />
                <input type="hidden" id="maxsv" name="maxsv" value="1000" />
               <div id="sv-range"></div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-listings">
    <h1>Current NHL Goaltenders</h1>
    <?php 
        session_start();


        if($_SESSION['allresults'])
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Player ORDER BY PlayerID ASC $limstring");

            if(isset($sortstats)){//THIS WORKS
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['sortStatsDesc'] = session_id();
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Player ORDER BY $sortstats DESC $limstring ");
            $filter = "sortstats={$sortDesc}";
            }

            if(isset($sortstatslow)) {//THIS WORKS
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['sortStatsAsc'] = session_id();
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Player ORDER BY $sortstatslow ASC $limstring ");
                $filter = "sortstatslow={$sortAsc}";
            }

            if(isset($minwins) || isset($maxwins) || isset($mingaa) || isset($maxgaa) || isset($minsv) || isset($maxsv))//THIS SEEMS TO WORK
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['customFilter'] = session_id();
                $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Player WHERE Wins BETWEEN '$minwins' AND '$maxwins' AND
                                                            GAA BETWEEN '$mingaa' AND '$maxgaa' AND SavePerc BETWEEN '$minsv' AND '$maxsv'
                                                            ORDER BY PlayerID ASC $limstring") or die (mysql_error());
                $filter = "getminwins={$minwins}&getmaxwins={$maxwins}&getmingaa={$mingaa}&getminsv={$minsv}&getmaxsv={$maxsv}";

            }
        }
        else if($_SESSION['sortStatsDesc'])//THIS WORKS
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Player ORDER BY $sortstats DESC $limstring ");
        }
        else if($_SESSION['sortStatsAsc'])//THIS WORKS
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Player ORDER BY $sortstatslow ASC $limstring ");
        }
        else if($_SESSION['customFilter'])//DON'T KNOW IF THIS IS DOING ANYTHING
        {

            $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Player WHERE Wins BETWEEN '$getminwins' AND '$getmaxwins' AND
                                                            GAA BETWEEN '$getmingaa' AND '$getmaxgaa' AND SavePerc BETWEEN '$getminsv' AND '$getmaxsv'
                                                            ORDER BY PlayerID ASC $limstring");
        }
        else{

        }

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $name = $row['LastName'] . ", " . $row['FirstName'];
            $wins = $row['Wins'];
            $pid = $row['PlayerID'];
            $image = $row['Picture'];
            $gaa = $row['GAA'];
            $sv = $row['SavePerc'];
            echo "<div class=\"player-listing\">";
            echo "<div class=\"image-holder\">";
            echo "<span class=\"helper\"></span>";
            echo "<a href=\"viewplayer.php?playerId=$pid\"><img src=\"admin/thumbs/$image\" alt=\"$name\"></a>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>";
            echo "<a href=\"viewplayer.php?playerId=$pid\">$name</a>";
            echo "<table align=\"center\">";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;\">Wins</td>";
            echo "<td style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;\">GAA</td>";
            echo "<td style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;\">SV%</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$wins</td>";
            echo "<td>$gaa</td>";
            echo "<td>.$sv</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo "</div>";
        }

        // paging links:
        echo "<div class=\"paging\">";
        if($postnum > $limit){
            echo "<span class=\"page-numbers\"><strong>Pages:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";
            $n = $pg + 1;
            $p = $pg - 1;
            $thisroot = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

            if($pg > 1){
                echo "<a href=\"$thisroot?pg=$p&$filter\"><< prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
            for($i=1; $i<=$num_pages; $i++){
                if($i!= $pg){
                    echo "<a href=\"$thisroot?pg=$i&$filter\">$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }else{
                    echo "$i&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }
            }
            if($pg < $num_pages){
                // INSERT QUERY STRING VARIBLE TO CARRY OVER DB QUERY
                echo "<a href=\"$thisroot?pg=$n&$filter\">next >></a>";
            }
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
        // end paging
        echo "</div>";

    ?>
    <br/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I fixed the paging issue by adding this into my code:

```
$getcount = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Player");

    if($_SESSION['customFilter']){
        $getcount = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Player WHERE Wins BETWEEN '$minwins' AND '$maxwins' AND
                                                        GAA BETWEEN '$mingaa' AND '$maxgaa' AND SavePerc BETWEEN '$minsv' AND '$maxsv'");
    }
```

But it's still giving me grief when I click next page. I don't think the filter values are carryying over for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the existing `session_start()` and add one on the first rule of the page, like:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

//Your html/js/php
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For session to works the very first instruction you have to call is "session_start()". You should call it only once and at the very beginning of your script.

```
<?php session_start() ?>
// rest of code PHP/HTML/JS/CSS/anything
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue, it behaves exactly the same way.